# Vuejs - Filters and sort, conflict?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I noticed a weird issue. using `table` component ([documentation](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table)) from `Element UI` and Vue2.js.

The filtering seems to be removed when we sort a column.

#### Steps to reproduce

1. Set the number of item to be displayed to 2
2. Activate the filter to display only the tag `Office`
3. Click on the column `name` to sort it.

#### Expected result

The table is filtered by tag `Office` and the column `name` is sorted alphabetically

#### Actual result

The table is **not filtered anymore by tag `Office`** and the column `name` is sorted alphabetically

You can find the issue [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2kqjzd0w/)

#### Questions

What is happening ?
How to avoid that ?

Comment: The table seems to cache the original data for sorting. It doesn't see updates to the computed. You'll need to use `filter-method` somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would do the trick

https://jsfiddle.net/yw18so9z/4/

```
 onSortChange(column){
    this.filter = this.filter.slice(0)
  },
```